# Specify output filename of Cloud Vision request

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-vision

So I'm sitting with Google Cloud Vision (for Node.js) and I'm trying to dynamically upload a document to a Google Cloud Bucket, process it using Google Cloud Vision API, and then downloading the .json afterwards. However, when Cloud Vision processes my request and places it in my bucket for saved text extractions, it appends `output-1-to-n.json` at the end of the filename. So let's say I'm processing a file called `foo.pdf` that's 8 pages long, the output will not be `foo.json` (even though I specified that), but rather be `foooutput1-to-8.json`.

Of course, this could be remedied by checking the page count of the PDF before uploading it and appending that to the path I search for when downloading, but that seems like such an unneccesary hacky solution. I can't seem to find anything in the documentation about not appending `output-1-to-n` to outputs. Extremely happy for any pointers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't specify a single output file for [asyncBatchAnnotate](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/files/asyncBatchAnnotate?hl=ko) because depending on your input, many files may get created. The output config is only a prefix and you have to do a wildcard search in gcs for your given prefix (so you should make sure your prefix is unique).

For more details see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55169298/11201290).