# Google Cloud Vision Api only return "name"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, vision-api

I am trying to use Google Cloud Vision API.

I am using the REST API in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/files/asyncBatchAnnotate?hl=ko&apix_params=%7B%22resource%22%3A%7B%22requests%22%3A%5B%7B%22inputConfig%22%3A%7B%22gcsSource%22%3A%7B%22uri%22%3A%22gs%3A%2F%2Fredaction-vision%2Fpdf_page1_employment_request.pdf%22%7D%2C%22mimeType%22%3A%22application%2Fpdf%22%7D%2C%22features%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION%22%7D%5D%2C%22outputConfig%22%3A%7B%22gcsDestination%22%3A%7B%22uri%22%3A%22gs%3A%2F%2Fredaction-vision%22%7D%7D%7D%5D%7D%7D#GcsSource).

**POST https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/files:asyncBatchAnnotate**

My request is

```
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "inputConfig": {
                "gcsSource": {
                    "uri": "gs://redaction-vision/pdf_page1_employment_request.pdf"
                },
                "mimeType": "application/pdf"
            },
            "features": [
                {
                    "type": "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION"
                }
            ],
            "outputConfig": {
                "gcsDestination": {
                    "uri": "gs://redaction-vision"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But the response is always only "name" like below:

```
{
    "name": "operations/a7e4e40d1e1ac4c5"
}
```

My "gs" location is valid.
When I write the wrong path in "gcsSource", 404 not found error is coming.
Who knows why my response is weird?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected, it will not send you the output as a HTTP response. To see what the API did, you need to go to your destination bucket and check for a file named "xxxxxxxxoutput-1-to-1.json", also, you need to specify the name of the object in your gcsDestination section, for example: `gs://redaction-vision/test`.

Comment: You are right, my "gcsDestination" was wrong path. I should have specified the path after "gs://redaction-version/". After add one more path, the json file was created.

Answer (score 1):

Since asyncBatchAnnotate is an asynchronous operation, it won't return the result, it instead returns the name of the operation. You can use that unique name to call [GetOperation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/operations/get) to check the status of the operation.

Note that there could be more than 1 output file for your pdf if the pdf has more pages than [batchSize](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/files/asyncBatchAnnotate#OutputConfig) and the output json file names change depending on the number of pages. It isn't safe to always append "output-1-to-1.json".

Make sure that the uri prefix you put in the output config is unique because you have to do a wildcard search in gcs on the prefix you provide to get all of the json files that were created.